# typescript issue incorrect return type in conditional type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to deal with conditional types in order to predict function output easier but in that case I don't understand at all that logic. As per my plan inside function "test" it should have fallen on ColleaguesCoordinatorReturnType but it gives me "never" instead. Why ? I have done all required checks.

Line 95 complaining about "never" ( `return {  Flow: MIXPANEL_FLOW.COLEAGUES, 'Registration ID': regId! };`)

[TYPESCRIPT PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMrADbAMYzAAmAQgIZEDmwAKgJ5jBwDeAUHHALICaGAogBkAYnAC8cAOSo6AZxwAzCQBp2XXoKEB9AMIB5AQL4BBAOIBVPhjGTpc7PM14I2XGUrJgM5ar0Hj5y01dADkBbmsJJxdgNw8ZTQhEbDpvDiMBACVjABFuTSyTAEkMGj4s7Ij0rKNc-L4ikrK+bIlWAF9WVhgGJgzgSm0IVDBcQiIABSgIMBlrNg4ofoBLGRgoMhglxPpGAH4ALkwcfDHyKloegG5VFcHo2OBDgCMIZxjEa4X+wqIDuFWoEtEJRrm1rqwkGguIUABrjIzBQSaIQCXQAdRYqh4-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-rqFXKfIpV8ZG6w1bqograJJwSb5FyMAFUHBQp4QrmuTV8h4A3TV8nbdjx-aDiO0JwiBU5gXOC5UreEjhgtgmxvGXp8T8ACEVaOhwHSg0AA)

I've reproduced this issue in the link above

```
export enum SelectedBadgeType {
  MYSELF = 'myself',
  MYSELF_COLLEAGUES = 'myself_colleagues',
  COLLEAGUES_ONLY = 'colleagues_only',
  ALREADY_REGISTERED = 'ALREADY_REGISTERED'
}

type RegCompletedProps = {
  registrationType?: SelectedBadgeType;
  isColleague: boolean;
  regId?: string;
};

enum MIXPANEL_FLOW {
  MYSELF = 'Myself',
  MYSELFANDCOLEAGUES = 'MyselfAndColleagues',
  COLEAGUES = 'ColleaguesOnly'
}

type ProductFields = {
  'Customer Type': string;
  'Product Name': string;
  'Product SKU': string;
};

type RegIdType = {
  'Registration ID': string;
};

type ProductArea = { 'Product Area': 'test' };


type ColleaguesCoordinatorReturnType = { Flow: MIXPANEL_FLOW.COLEAGUES } & ProductArea & RegIdType & Pick<ProductFields, 'Customer Type'>;

type ColleaguesReturnType = { Flow: MIXPANEL_FLOW.COLEAGUES } & ProductArea & ProductFields;

type RegCompletedReturnType<T extends RegCompletedProps = RegCompletedProps> = T extends { registrationType: SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY; isColleague: false }
  ? ColleaguesCoordinatorReturnType
  : T extends { registrationType: SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY; isColleague: true }
  ? ColleaguesReturnType
  : never;

  function test({
    registrationType,
    isColleague,
    regId,
  }:RegCompletedProps):RegCompletedReturnType{
    if(registrationType===SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY && isColleague){
      return {  Flow: MIXPANEL_FLOW.COLEAGUES, 'Registration ID': regId! };
    }
  }
```

Comment: @jcalz Done. sorry

Comment: And could you pare it down to have fewer conditions while still capturing the problem? Part of the point of a [mre] is to be *minimal*; if it needs scrolling to look at then it's probably longer than ideal.

Comment: @jcalz Yep, I've just reduced amount of redundant code and it's still reproducible, updated link and code

Comment: Is `test` supposed to be generic?  Since it isn't, you should at least make it so that `RegCompletedReturnType` without a type argument is a union of the possible types, maybe like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wvk8Bw) shows.  The value you're returning there is missing some stuff and there's a some paths missing return issue, so I'm not sure how you want to handle that.  Does that playground link approach meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, that works much better now but still have some questions. look here [link](https://tsplay.dev/W4bpAN)

Comment: @jcalz So I wanted to return a specific type based on those flags in function props. So I expected that T extends would work but somehow it didn't

Comment: Because `test` doesn't mention a `T` at all; it's not generic.  You can make it generic if you want like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nav0om), but the compiler will never be able to follow the logic inside the implementation of a generic function returning a generic conditional type, as described in [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  Right now that's a limitation of TypeScript and if you need the compiler to follow generic logic in the function body then you'll have to completely refactor away from conditional types.

Comment: How do you want to proceed with this question?  The scope seems to be expanding so once we decide what the primary issue is we should [edit] the question to focus on it more narrowly.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for explanation . There won't be anything generic in this function, I planned to use just RegCompletedProps as an argument in this function and check flags and conditionally return different types. I used generic simply because of my poor understanding and thought that it was only solution. If you say that I can make it without generic, let's proceed with this thing

Comment: You mean [this version](https://tsplay.dev/N5A29N)? I could do that but then if you're not using a generic at all, then it collapses to just [this version](https://tsplay.dev/ND8GON) with no conditional types at all.  I'm kind of skeptical that this is what you want.  If you want the output of a function to have a type that depends on the input, you'll need generics or overloads.  I could try showing you overloads but could you implement the function properly for the example first?

Comment: @jcalz Yep you're right I want to get concrete type after using my function.

Comment: What does "concrete" mean?  Does it mean "not a union"?  Anyway please [edit] to provide a [mre] that shows you calling the function in different ways and the types you expect to come out for each one, and also implement the function so that it works at runtime even if the compiler complains.  Then I could probably show how to give it typings that work.

Comment: @jcalz I can implement this function around our minimal reproducible example. Also I tried to pass values manually and condition seems to work correctly but something f*cked up with that function typing. [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9Op1W)

Comment: @jcalz just have done it , ocassionaly pressed enter button :)

Comment: Great, thanks.  So [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMzV1W) is how I'd do it with overloads; you add a call signature for each way of calling it, and an implementation that works for all of them.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That definitely does meet my needs but I've never thought nor used overloads. Thanks. I will use that approach. Make answer I will select it as a solution

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, if you want the type returned from a function to depend on the types of the arguments to the function, then you either need to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) or [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Generic functions are good for representing *programmatic* or *general* relationships between inputs and output.  If you have a whole continuous range of possible input types and they correspond to a whole range of possible output types, you probably want a generic function.  When you *call* such a function the compiler will infer the generic type argument(s) and then use those to determine the return type. *Implementing* a generic function properly can be tough because it's harder to convince the compiler that what you're doing matches the call signature for every possible specification of its type parameter(s).  Indeed if the return type is complicated, like a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), then it's essentially impossible to implement in a way the compiler can verify as type safe.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), and currently you'll need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to loosen the type checking for it to compile.

Overloads on the other hand are when you list out a small finite number of call signatures for the same function implementation.  If you have a small number of cases for how you call the function and there's no obvious way to generalize the input-output relationship other than listing the cases, then you might to use overloads.  When you *call* such a function the compiler tries each call signature in turn until it finds one that matches, and then it will use that call signature including the return type.  *Implementing* an overloaded function is fairly easy, because the compiler only checks the return value loosely against the call signatures.  It's kind of *too* easy, because you might return the wrong type for a particular call signature, and the compiler won't catch it.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235) requesting a way to safely evaluate overload bodies, which was closed as too complex.  So overload implementations are checked loosely, meaning you need to be careful to do the right thing.

---

In your example code, you've written a generic type `RegCompletedReturnType<T>` and presumably you could write `test()` as a generic function that returns that type.  But it's ugly because the definition of `RegCompletedReturnType<T>` looks like it just checks cases one by one (`T extends I1 ? O1 : T extends I2 ? O2 : ⋯`) and the implementation also checks cases one by one.  You *could* do it, but it feels like a mismatch for generics.

Since you have a few ways you want to call it and you want to check them one by one, an overloaded function might be more appropriate. Let's try that.

First you need to declare your call signatures in whatever order you'd like them checked.  Possibly:

```
function test(props: {
  registrationType: SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY,
  isColleague: true,
  regId?: string
}): ColleaguesReturnType;

function test(props: {
  registrationType: SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY,
  isColleague: false,
  regId?: string
}): ColleaguesCoordinatorReturnType;
```

And then after that you write out the implementation:

```
function test({
  registrationType,
  isColleague,
  regId,
}: RegCompletedProps) {
  if (registrationType === SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY && isColleague) {
    return {
      "Customer Type": "some value from arguments", "Product Area": "test",
      Flow: MIXPANEL_FLOW.COLEAGUES, "Product Name": "Name", "Product SKU": "sku"
    }
  }
  if (registrationType === SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY && !isColleague) {
    return {
      "Customer Type": "some value from arguments", "Product Area": "test",
      Flow: MIXPANEL_FLOW.COLEAGUES, "Registration ID": regId
    };
  }
  throw new Error('unknown value');
}
```

This all compiles with no error, but remember that you need to be careful; if you edit that implementation and replace the `isColleague` check with a `!isColleague` check, there will *still* be no error.  Overload implementations are checked loosely.  That means you should double check that you've done it right.

Anyway, let's see how it looks to callers:

```
const coordinator = test(
  {
    registrationType: SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY,
    isColleague: false, regId: "reg-id"
  });
// const coordinator: ColleaguesCoordinatorReturnType

const colleagues = test({
  registrationType: SelectedBadgeType.COLLEAGUES_ONLY,
  isColleague: true, regId: "reg-id"
});
// const colleagues: ColleaguesReturnType
```

Looks good; the return values are what you want them to be.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMrADbAMYzAAmAQgIZEDmwAKgJ5jBwDeAUHHALICaGAogBkAYnAC8cAOSo6AZxwAzCQBp2XXoKEB9AMIB5AQL4BBAOIBVPhjGTpc7PM14I2XGUrJgM5ar0Hj5y01dADkBbmsJJxdgNw8ZTQhEbDpvDiMBACVjABFuTSyTAEkMGj4s7Ij0rKNc-L4ikrK+bIlWAF9WVhgGJgzgSm0IVDBcQiIABSgIMBlrNg4ofoBLGRgoMhglxPpGAH4ALkwcfDHyKloegG5VFcHo2OBDgCMIZxjEa4X+wqIDuFWoEtEJRrm1rqwkGguIUABrjIzBQSaIQCXQAdRYqh4-GEEU4sgUqTUOKECOyvn8Fis4gk+Ls8iMiCId1c7k8RIppipERZMTZMl0SRS7U63UYcEmECIyAIQiWOCIs3E80k2mQqyGwCgcB2wAkhwBQJBqgkkulBDgwTIqD1BrWRs+kjNMvgGAA0mZ9f97cDQeCxb1vkRdXMTX1KCs1hstog4IUWnbAb72v6ehKpuaYEZFmQ5k6My64NmYl6JIRVhI4GDOl007yHjJBtAiECNtA+jBkFBECHlXAhNgIAB3Q6cWHwxECZGotEAOk5ASsbTgADJ01KXcXc2vwz8Q2vxks8ABrAA8ztl8uwiqUqvVME12t1EgAfKnxfX+R2uz2032B8Oo7jgiSIoui876JSlhVqu66ZlusEXjAcoKjI4IAPToXAeBkC4-xLJQiAbF2nidPIyCIAQMZwOWMAABRgFMMyHCqiwRgC0bbD0hxYLgBDEGc1C6hBfhcoEIRhCoHC3M4rIeIcaweFJcBsT8fyGsC7QAJSHJ+cTft2urguRlGbIkNGePRjHTDILGqGxkbrGZv6MDxxz8aQFBCT0ImGGJGBBKE3DKTJ9xsoc8i4XIymqb8iZGtpumyXycRNlALZEQ+UAGS5wAYVhSzDLgNqIDAnGIGRFFUeZtF0axywcc5uohY2yUPDFQYqG0hzhoMRXAGMkozFpmLSfIcB0Q5jUxr2ojiLxJwCV5FyML5UEBRJ4QrmuoVycAI0ql8nbdqNHBnQARGqGo2k+PTnYc50yJqcAAG64R4cDyFM6BkFA7glTAMjnbe51IUWOb3XA520cDqhnf2g4jtCcIgVOYFzguVIg2DVo2pD5248AwNQ2D7pmPjMjHsg51w1WqgdGNE1TVGTV-nNRx8acy3Cb4fmLoFYSrmuACEu0pftp1HT+ksXVdD43Tqd0PU9Nqve9TBfUMcC-f9SCA8ToMFhaW74zDynwwBSNjijk7TuBmOWCD4aOeVcbZJDsW09WHAMzRAAWUxDnAiDAEHfBQFMUB0RIFHHogw6xm92AeBIWmgp0TiIKs2GvOlrZZdYtWqIdKkNSzM3cRzi2eecPP6HzVIC8FtNiw8EVRcAt6xQ9bEALRLEQNM+2nrCYTnWfwE4zb59ASVhalucZW22UDT+uqsJn2dRHtSoWasdWl+x5dca5VceYJK3AGt-lN1JrfhTRUBKYfPw9-0-eD1WI9j5vk9tfyc8d45XXkAA)